# Почему функция, принимающая список, изменяет свой аргумент и делает его равным результату

Tags: python, python-3.x

Почему RGB в предпоследнем print равняется RGB255? Что не так?

```
def makeRGB(l):
    mtx = []
    for j in l:
        mtx.append(list(j))
    return mtx


def makeRGB255(mtx):
    for (i, mtxRow) in enumerate(mtx):
        for (j, mtxElem) in enumerate (mtxRow):
            mtx[i][j] = round(float(mtxElem)/255,3)
    return mtx


def main():
    r = [(0, 0, 0), (255, 130, 92), (93, 227, 169)]

    RGB = makeRGB(r)
    print (RGB)
    RGB255 = makeRGB255(RGB)

    print (RGB)
    print (RGB255)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Вывод:

```
[[0, 0, 0], [255, 130, 92], [93, 227, 169]]
[[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [1.0, 0.51, 0.361], [0.365, 0.89, 0.663]]
[[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [1.0, 0.51, 0.361], [0.365, 0.89, 0.663]]
```

Comment: Добрый вечер, не любят тут такие вопросы ;) Установите [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/#section=linux) (абсолютно бесплатно) и дебажте код на здоровье. И лучше не ставить такой заголовок, заминусуют...

Comment: ну а вообще прикол в том, что в `makeRGB255` изменяя `mtx` внутри функции вы изменяете значение глобально, так как в функцию передаётся ссылка на объект. По этому у вас `RGB` и `RGB255` указывают на одит и тот же объект. Хотите чтобы были раздельными - создайте внутри функции переменную `ans` в которую и записывайте ответ

Comment: related: [In Python, why can a function modify some arguments as perceived by the caller, but not others?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/575196/4279)

Comment: @Эникейщик: здесь нет никакой копии ни глубокой, ни поверхностной в makeRGB255() (ровно один объект [список]).

Comment: @jfs Да, невнимательно смотрел.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас функция изменяет список, который ей был передан как аргумент и возвращает его же.

Питон никогда не копирует объекты, передаваемые в функцию при вызове. Список с именем `RGB`, при вызове `makeRGB255()` получает ещё одно имя `mtx` на время вызова функции ([как `b = a` работает в Питоне](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables)). Поэтому `RGB255` список не просто то же самое значение имеет (`RGB == RGB255`), более того это тот же список (`RGB is RGB255`) — один и тот же объект.

Чтобы избежать подобных ошибок, в Питоне многие функции следуют [Command–query separation принципу](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation): если функция изменяет ввод, то она должна вернуть `None`, если ввод не меняется, то новый объект возвращается. Типичный пример: `L.sort()` метод сортирует список по месту и ничего не возращает, `new = sorted(L)` функция не изменяет `L` список и возвращает новый `new` [отсортированный] список.