# Pandas, объединение двух DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Есть стандартный датасет Титаника: `train` и `test`

Хочу подготовить данные для моделей, модифицируя их, и, соответственно, есть желание делать преобразования сразу в `test` и `train`

`full_data = [train, test]`

Далее запускаю циклы, например:

```
for dataset in full_data:
    dataset['*col_name*'] = dataset['*col_name*'].apply(function)
```

Они работают и если я вызываю `train` или `test`, то я получаю `DF` после необходимых мне преобразований

Проблема возникла вот в этом коде:

```
for dataset in full_data:
    polym = pd.DataFrame(poly.fit_transform(dataset[['Age', 'Fare']]))
    dataset = pd.concat([dataset, polym], axis=1)
```

В результате, если я вызову объект `train`, то он будет без изменений, а если вызову объект `dataset`, то он как раз будет содержать `DF` того вида, которого мне нужно (будут добавлены нелинейные преобразования некоторых признаков)

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно написать цикл, чтобы преобразования применялись и сохранялись для `train` и `test` соответственно

P.S. думал, что может проблемы с `pd.concat()`, но вроде бы ясно как он работает. Не могу понять почему преобразованный `DF` он записывает на новую переменную `dataset`, а не на `train` / `test`

Спасибо!

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Как реализован цикл for? Почему `for x in a: x=1` не меняет `a` список](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/750868/23044)

Comment: если вы хотите одинаковые действия для двух наборов данных выполнить, то можно определить функцию, которая только с одними данными работает и вызвать эту функцию дважды. Обратите внимание, если вы меняете данные по месту, то эта функция ничего не должна возвращать, если вы новые данные создаёте, то не изменяйте ввод, а возвращайте результат: `train, test = map(modified, [train, test])`. См. объяснение: [Почему функция, принимающая список, изменяет свой аргумент и делает его равным результату](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/819976/23044)

Comment: [связанный вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49466193/how-to-add-a-feature-to-a-vectorized-data-set)